# How to access the first element in a pointer to an array using the C mysql API

Tags: mysql, c, arrays

I am trying to implement part of the mysql C API to retrieve one known field which will be a TINYINT value (boolean, either 1 or 0)

The mysql C API offers a type which is a pointer to an array MYSQL_ROW row; where the elements of the array are accessed via row[i] where i is the index. The elements are returned as strings whatever the data type in the database.

The field I am trying to access is obviously boolean and will be either 1 or 0 if the query finds the field. I want to do a logic check as to the value of this field but am struggling with types. I tried casting row[i] to an int but no good, I seem to get the pointer returned. I know that C doesn't have a native bool type but can be implemented. Any ideas there would be welcome.. here's my code, many thanks in advance - Paul

```
void process_result_set (MYSQL *conn, MYSQL_RES *res_set) {

MYSQL_ROW row;
unsigned int i;
unsigned int logonstatus;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row (res_set)) != NULL)
{
for (i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields (res_set); i++)
{

    logonstatus = (int)(row[i]); // gives an int return but appears to     return a memory location i.e. a pointer
    printf("The value of logon status is: %d\n", logonstatus);
    printf("\nThe value of the logon field is:%s\n", row[i]);

}

}
if (mysql_errno (conn) != 0)
    print_error (conn, "mysql_fetch_row() failed");
else
printf ("%lu rows returned\n",(unsigned long) mysql_num_rows (res_set));
}
```

Comment: can you show an example output when you run this?

Comment: I assume row[i] is the pointer to the row number i so because a row has one or more columns you have to address the right one Like row[i][0] For the ele contained in the first col.

Comment: In answer to your questions, yes is it a pointer to an array which for that particular field only one element will ever exist and will be set to 1 or 0 or the field won't be there initially from the query I am running.

The 2 printf statements do the same thing, one passing a int, the other a string which is how data is returned from a DB when using the mysql api.

Many Thanks for you help.

The output that I am getting is as follows:

Comment: (~/museuminfo) localhost $ ./museumDB

Connecting to MySQL Server...

Connection Successful

The SELECT statement you have built is: SELECT logon_status FROM users WHERE userpin='2468'
The value of logon status is: 146753048

The value of the logon field is:1
1 rows returned